Math format bug for \mathbf command in TeXLive 2023/2024
I found that the command "\mathbf" may not work well in the following condition:

TeXLive version:2023/2024
\usepackage{upgreek}
math format: "$\mathbf{H}^{\mathsf xxx}$"

I am not sure this is caused by package corruption or a package bug.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[journal,twoside,web]{ieeecolor}
\usepackage{generic}
\usepackage{upgreek}%The \mathbf{H} will work normally if this pakcage is removed
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%%------ package------%
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\hat{\boldsymbol\thetaup}}={{({{\mathbf{H}}^{\top}}{{\mathbf{R}}^{-1}}\mathbf{H})}^{-1}}{{\mathbf{H}}^{\top}}{{\mathbf{R}}^{-1}}\mathbf{z} 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{\hat{\boldsymbol\thetaup}}={{({{\mathbf{H}}^{\mathsf T}}{{\mathbf{R}}^{-1}}\mathbf{H})}^{-1}}{{\mathbf{H}}^{\mathsf T}}{{\mathbf{R}}^{-1}}\mathbf{z} 
\end{align}
\end{document}

A overleaf link is provided here for your convenience.
https://www.overleaf.com/read/xgqgysqnbsjm#55f903

Since you're using the newtxmath math font package, you probably shouldn't be bothering with the upgreek package at all. I.e., just write \uptheta, etc. to get upright-greek letters that are stylistically compatible with their slanted variants. Put differently, no need for \thetaup of the upgreek package.
Some additional comments, in no particular order:

You should apply \mathbf to latin-alphabet letters only -- and only if you want upright lettering. Use \bm or \boldsymbol for greek-alphabet letters and non-alphabetic symbols. Use \bm for latin-alphabet letters if you want slanted lettering.

There's no need to bold-face the "hat" symbol that's placed above \bm{\uptheta} (or \boldsymbol{\uptheta}).

Don't overdo it with the { and } characters in math formulas.



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\hat{\bm\uptheta}={(\mathbf{H}^{\top} \mathbf{R}^{-1} \mathbf{H})}^{\!-1}%
                  \mathbf{H}^{\top} \mathbf{R}^{-1} \mathbf{z} 
\]
\end{document}


There are several problems with your code:

the excess in braces makes it hard to read and even harder to type
bm should be loaded after the math font package
amssymb (and amsfonts) should not be loaded together with newtxmath
The problem stems from the braces, actually.

The class ieeecolor likely uses ptm for the text font, which is really bad nowadays and you should simply load newtx.
Since newtx has upright Greek letters, you don't need upgreek.
Since you seem to be using \mathbf{\hat{...}} for a boldface hat, it's simpler to use \bm.
\documentclass[journal,twoside,web]{ieeecolor}

\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}% after the math font package!

\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\tp}{{\mathsf{T}}}% always ^\tp

\definecolor{subsectioncolor}{rgb}{0,0.541,0.855} % to keep ieeecolor happy

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\bm{\hat{\uptheta}}=
(\matr{H}^{\top}\matr{R}^{-1}\matr{H})^{-1}\matr{H}^{\top}\matr{R}^{-1}\matr{z} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\bm{\hat{\uptheta}}=
(\matr{H}^\tp\matr{R}^{-1}\matr{H})^{-1}\matr{H}^\tp\matr{R}^{-1}\matr{z} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}


Note that I defined semantic commands instead of the generic \mathbf.
Avoid using align for single equations.
